# JSONArray with ":" character in Android

Tags: android, json

```
 {"1": {
         "StoreName": "イオン八千代緑が丘店",
         "StoreTel": "047-480-3660",
         "StoreAddress": "〒276-0049 千葉県八千代市緑ヶ丘２－１－３　２Ｆ",
         "WorkingTimeInNormalDay": "7:30 AM - 9:00PM",
         "WorkingTimeInWeekend": "9:00-22:00",
         "HaveKidProduct": "N"
     }}
```

i want to read this json:

```
JSONObject json ,jChild;
JSONArray jsonNames, jsonValues;
JSONArray jChildNames,jChildValues;
json = new JSONObject(resultString);

jsonNames = json.names();
jsonValues = json.toJSONArray(jsonNames);
for (int i = 0; i < jsonNames.length(); i++) {
jChild = jsonValues.getJSONObject(i);
jChildNames = jChild.names();
jChildValues = jChild.toJSONArray(jChildNames);

Log.i(getCallingPackage(), "No : " + jsonNames.getString(i));
                for (int j = 0; j < jChildNames.length(); j++){
                    Log.i(getCallingPackage(),jChildNames.getString(j) + " : " + jChildValues.getString(j).trim());

                }

}
}
```

There problems here is:
When i parse this:

"WorkingTimeInNormalDay": "7:30 AM - 9:00PM", i have

jChildValues.getString(j) return "7" not "7:30 AM - 9:00PM"

i think may be ":" character is the root cause

How can i solve this problems?

Thanks

===========

Edited:

This is my mistake

Everything working like a champ

Comment: No, `"7:30 AM - 9:00PM"` shouldn't be causing any problem as its enclosed within double quotes

Comment: but if i dont have "WorkingTimeInNormalDay": "7:30 AM - 9:00PM",
         "WorkingTimeInWeekend": "9:00-22:00",  everything is correct

Comment: I think it's an encoding problem. Print your json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, there is no problems with ":" character.

There is a my big mistake.

Everything is work well

Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Before parsing the json try to print the total json string so that you will know that "WorkingTimeInNormalDay": "7:30 AM - 9:00PM" is coming correctly or not.
Because if you parse the json the WorkingTimeInNormalDay will give you 7:30 AM - 9:00PM

Comment: "StoreName": "イオン八千代緑が丘店",
         "StoreTel": "047-480-3660",
         "StoreAddress": "〒276-0049 千葉県八千代市緑ヶ丘２－１－３　２Ｆ",  i can parse correctly all of them

Comment: Yeah, the example JSON appears to be correctly formatted (by adding the missing {} required to make it a JSON object) - so it seems your actual input is invalid. If you are getting the JSON from an externally available source you should consider running it through an [on-line validator, such as this](http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Answer (score 1):

well it worked here:

```
 String json = "{\"1\": [{\"StoreName\": \"イオン八千代緑が丘店\",\"StoreTel\": \"047-480-          3660\"," +
                "\"StoreAddress\": \"〒276-0049 千葉県八千代市緑ヶ丘２－１－３　２Ｆ\"," +
                "\"WorkingTimeInNormalDay\": \"7:30 AM - 9:00PM\"," +
                "\"WorkingTimeInWeekend\": \"9:00-22:00\"," +
                "\"HaveKidProduct\": \"N\"" +
                "}]}";


            try {
                JSONObject e = new JSONObject(json);
                JSONArray jArray = e.getJSONArray("1");
                 for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject obj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 System.out.println(obj.getString("WorkingTimeInNormalDay"));
                }

                System.out.println(jArray.getString(0));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
```

Comment: I did not escape it if you look more carefully. I did not escape the : sign. I escaped the double quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Google GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) library for Android. 
You can with ease add your own parsers for specific data types.

For instance:

```
public class DateDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Date>
{
    public Date deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException
    {
        String JSONDateToMilliseconds = "\\/(Date\\((.*?)(\\+.*)?\\))\\/";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(JSONDateToMilliseconds);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(json.getAsJsonPrimitive().getAsString());
        String result = matcher.replaceAll("$2");

        return new Date(new Long(result));
    }
}
```

Comment: but that will make you package that library with your apk instead of just using the native one.